# dlib c++ : slow convergence

Tags: c++, optimization, dlib

I am trying to use dlib for a real time application. I am using `find_min_global` in dlib to optimize a function with 2 variables. The problem is that it is taking too long to converge.
If I use `find_min_global(optimizationFunction, lowValue, highValue, std::chrono::milliseconds(10))`, I dont get any optmization at all. The returned values are the same as input values. I do get far better results with `find_min_global(optimizationFunction, lowValue, highValue, std::chrono::milliseconds(100))` but I cannot afford to spend 100 milisecs on this problem. Is there any way i can speed this up or any other function/library that can help me achieve this?

```
minimizeSSE()
{
    auto optimize = [&](float x, float y)
    {
        float totalError = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        {
            totalError += ((a[i] - x)*(a[i]- x) + (b[i] - y)*(b[i]- y));
        }
        return totalError;
    }

    column_vector lowerBound = {0, 0};
    column_vector upperBound = {100, 100};

    auto res = find_min_global(optimize, lowerBound, upperBound, std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Here, `column_vector` is `typedef matrix<double,0,1> column_vector;`
The variable `res` has optimized values of `x` and `y`. If I run the function `minimizeSSE()` , it gives me optimal values but if I run the function for 10 milisecs, I dont get any optimization.

The value of `N` in the loop count, is not more than a few 100s. I dont have millions of values over which I have to optimize `x` and `y`, at max a few 100s.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Added some code, hope that helps you help me !

Comment: What are a and b? Have you tried using built in math functions to do the square? There are also math libraries out there, if the standard ones are too slow.

Comment: You could also probably benefit from memoization, depending on what your data looks like. I suspect you are calculating the exact same result many times over. _if_ you have the extra space.

Comment: a and b are arrays which have the values over which i need the optimize x and y